# C# equals but regardless of the order

Tags: c#, equality

I hava a class Edge which looks like following

```
class Edge 
{
    public Node left { get; private set; }
    public Node right { get; private set; }
    public int Costs { get; private set; }
}
```

I want to write an equals which returns true regardless of the order. So when left is 'Paris' and right is 'Rom' I want to return true if it compares with an Edge where right is 'Paris' and left is 'Rom'.

'Rom' and 'Paris' are the names of the Node class. The node class just has a field for the name.

I tried to write my own equals like that

```
  public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Edge edge &&
               (EqualityComparer<Node>.Default.Equals(left, edge.left) || EqualityComparer<Node>.Default.Equals(right, edge.left)) &&
               (EqualityComparer<Node>.Default.Equals(right, edge.right) || EqualityComparer<Node>.Default.Equals(right, edge.left));
    }
```

And I add edges to a HashSet of Edges.

I am little bit clueless about what I should try.

Comment: This is gunna need more information. What property is `Paris`/`Rom` what are they? How is this used? What are we comparing with `Edge`?

Comment: `public bool Equals(Edge other) => return left == other.left || right == other.right;` you could also [override `==`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) if you want

Comment: This feels like a class problem you are trying to have SO solve for you. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Override ToString and use it to compare.

Comment: *"'Rom' and 'Paris' are the names of the Node class"* -- Where is the `Node` class? If it's relevant to the problem, you should edit the question and include it.

Comment: You need your `Equals` to be something like (pseudo-code): `equals = (left == edge.left && right == edge.right) || (left == edge.right && right == edge.left)`.

Comment: One issue is that you might be doing reference equality for the `Node` class if it doesn't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.  the second issue is with your logic.  You want `(left == edge.Left && right == edge.Right) || (left == edge.Right && right == edge.Left)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code checks if the `left` value of one edge is in either the `left` or `right` field of the other edge AND if the `right` value of one edge is in either the `left` or `right` field. This can lead to the following wrong `Equals()` checks:

```
edge 1: (42, 50)
            / |
           /  |   
          /   |
edge 2: (50, 50)
```

In this case you will find one "cross" link and one "straight" link, depending on where you start your `Equals()` call from. But the checks should be either both "cross" or both "straight".

You can change the checks in the `Equals()` method as follow:

```
public sealed override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return obj is Edge edge &&
           (
               (
                   // L1 == L2 && R1 == R2
                   EqualityComparer<Node>.Default.Equals(Left, edge.Left) &&
                   EqualityComparer<Node>.Default.Equals(Right, edge.Right)
               ) ||
               (
                   // L1 == R2 && R1 == L2
                   EqualityComparer<Node>.Default.Equals(Left, edge.Right) &&
                   EqualityComparer<Node>.Default.Equals(Right, edge.Left)
               )
           );
}
```

The first block checks if the one `Left` goes to the other `Left` and the one `Right` goes to the other `Right`. The second block checks the "crossed" part, where one `Left` goes to the other `Right` and the one `Right` goes to the other `Left`.